# Using sklearn's roc_auc_score for OneVsOne Multi-Classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, multiclass-classification

So I am working on a model that attempts to use RandomForest to classify samples into 1 of 7 classes. I'm able to build and train the model, but when it comes to evaluating it using roc_auc function, I'm able to perform 'ovr' (oneVsrest) but 'ovo' is giving me some trouble.

`roc_auc_score(y_test, rf_probs, multi_class = 'ovr', average = 'weighted')`

The above works wonderfully, I get my output, however, when I switch multi_class to 'ovo' which I understand might be better with class imbalances, I get the following error:

`roc_auc_score(y_test, rf_probs, multi_class = 'ovo')`

> IndexError: too many indices for array

(I pasted the whole traceback below!)

Currently my data is set up as follow:

y_test (61,1)

y_probs (61, 7)

Do I need to reshape my data in a special way to use 'ovo'?

In the documentation, https://thomasjpfan.github.io/scikit-learn-website/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html, it says "**binary y_true, y_score is supposed to be the score of the class with greater label. The multiclass case expects shape = [n_samples, n_classes] where the scores correspond to probability estimates.**"

Additionally, the whole traceback seems to hint as using maybe using a more binary array (hopefully that's the right term! I'm new to this!)

[image]

Very, very thankful for any ideas/thoughts!

Comment: Yes. You need to reshape the y_test to shape ``(61, 7)``. You can do that easily by using ``OneHotEncoder``. I haven't tried it yet but this should do it

Comment: @TirthPatel thank you, that did the trick! Wow, such a simple solution, i spent days on this!

Answer (score 0):

@Tirth Patel provided the right answer, I needed to reshape my test set using one hot encoding. Thank you!